# is there a simple way to convert Date(sql) to following format Month(3 character) day(int) , year(2014)

Tags: java, javascript, sql, postgresql

is there a simple way to convert Date(sql) to following format Month(3 character) day(int) , year(int)?

For example:
 Jan 3, 2014
 Feb 2, 2014
I have this: "2014-02-14"

(i use postgresql, java and javascript on client)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming , if you want to achieve this in the Database side itself. Then use the below sql query.

Lets say "stack" is the column containing your DATE value ie "2014-02-14"

```
select to_char(stack,'Mon dd, YYYY') from testing;
```

```
to_char
--
Feb 14, 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Java's [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) API

You can do something like this --

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, YYYY");
String dateString = format.format(date); // Pass your SQL date object here
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");

    SimpleDateFormat sqlformat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");

    java.util.Date date;
    try {
        date = sqlformat.parse("2014-02-14");
        String result = format.format(date);
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } // Pass your SQL date object here
```

Comment: Thanks, but now it returns always January for Month

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

In Joda-Time 2.3 (substitute your desired time zone and Locale)…

```
String output = DateTimeFormat.forStyle( "M-" ).withLocale( new java.util.Locale( "fr", "CA" ).withTimeZone( "America/Montreal").print( new DateTime( myJavaDotSqlDotJavaObject ) );
```

## A Date-Time Object Has No Format

You are making the common mistake of conflating a date-time value with its string representation. **A java.sql.Date object has no String format.** You can generate a String representation from a date-time object, but the two are separate independent objects.

## ISO 8601

The format you mentioned is defined by the [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) date-time library uses ISO 8601 for its defaults for both inputs and outputs.

## Time Zone

Both the question and other answers ignore the crucial issue of time zone.

Determining what day it is (yesterday, today, tomorrow) depends on your time zone. While a new day dawns in Paris for Feb 2, in Montréal the date is still Feb 1.

A [java.sql.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) instance has no time zone. It's date-time value internally is effectively in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (no offset).

## Decent Date-Time Library

The bundled java.util.Date and .Calendar classes in Java are notoriously troublesome. Avoid them. Use either:

- [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)
- The new [java.time package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) in Java 8.

## Joda-Time

Some example code in Joda-Time 2.3.

Get the current date-time.

```
DateTimeZone timeZoneParis = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/Paris" );
DateTime nowInParis = DateTime.now( timeZone );
```

To convert your java.sql.Date instance to a Joda-Time object, simply pass it to the constructor. Be sure to include a time zone to be assigned to the Joda-Time [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) object. If you omit the time zone, the JVM’s default zone is assigned.

```
DateTime dateTimeInParis = new DateTime( myJavaDotSqlDotDateObject, timeZoneParis );
```

Adjust for time zone.

```
DateTimeZone timeZoneMontréal = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Montreal" );
DateTime nowInMontréal = nowInParis.withTimeZone( timeZone );
```

You may adjust to UTC. This might be helpful for debugging, to verify the UTC value stored in your database. [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) **always stores `TIMESTAMP` types in UTC**. I repeat: *both* `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` and `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` types are stored in UTC. The 'with' or 'without' names are misleading, as they refer not to storage but to whether or not a time zone is respected during insertion into or retrieval from the database. [Expert advice says](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/use-timestamptz.html): Always use `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
DateTime dateTimeInUtc = nowInMontréal.withTimeZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Generate a string representation of the date-time value using one of the built-in ISO 8601 formatters. For the date-only `YYYY-MM-DD` format you mentioned, call the factory method [`ISODateTimeFormat.date()`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#date%28%29).

For the `MMM DD, YYYY` format you want, I suggest you instead use a localized format. See the line of code at the top of this answer for an example. Pass "M-" to generate a medium-length string representation of the date portion while omitting the time portion. Pass "F", "L", "M", or "S" for Full, Long, Medium, and Short.

If you insist on exactly your specified format, you may create a formatter using the `DateTimeFormat.forPattern` method. Search StackOverflow for many examples.

Note that the formatter can do the time zone adjusting as part of its process, as an alternative to the time zone adjustment we saw above. The formatter can also localize.

```
DateTimeFormat formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.date().withTimeZone( timeZoneMontréal ).withLocale( new java.util.Locale( "fr", "CA" ); // Factory producing formatters.
String outputDateOnlyInMontréal = formatter.print( nowInParis );
```